# Using Hashids with strings

Tags: php, hashids

I looking for a way to generate a short, unique, immutable and reversible ID from an original string. I found the perfect library [Hashids](http://hashids.org/) for that but it only wants integer in input, and I also have letters.

I don't want to use common encryption algorithms because the output is very long.

I can achieve that with `base64_encode` but I want to hash with a passphrase to prevent direct decoding from unwanted people.

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: Tried Hashing ?

Comment: Sorry I edited the post, I need that the output string was reversible to the original input so hashing isn't a suitable option

Comment: Sir @fede91it, may I know how you installed hashids.js on your angular project?

Comment: I used the PHP version, not the JS one

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you found the "perfect library" for your needs. From the website;

> Do not encode strings. We've had several requests to add this feature — "it seems so easy to add". We will not add this feature for security purposes, doing so encourages people to encode sensitive data, like passwords. This is the wrong tool for that.

Comment: I read that, and I find it a big nonsense. I do not have to crypt any sensitive data but I would hide the hashed information to the people. I think the people must decide what technical tool to use for each situation.

Comment: @fede91it well, obviously the author(s) of that library doesn't think it is nonsense. But since it is open source you are free to fork it and add the feature you are missing.

Comment: Yes I think I'll do soon, but I've to understand the encryption alghoritm